# How to access ViewControllers from Storyboard and add some code to them?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

I have created couple ViewControllers in Storyboard and managed segues. How to access those ViewControllers and add some code to them ?

Comment: You may need to actually learn a lot more Objective-C before thinking about development.  Get yourself a good book!

Answer (score 4):

If you are new to Xcode, Objective C and iOS (but already know how to code) then I recommend you follow a couple of tutorials as all your questions will be answered: [Ray Wenderlich - iOS by tutorials](http://www.raywenderlich.com)